# Which shotguns mics should I consider for capturing SFX?

Tags: shotgun, microphone, record

Hey,

I know everybody hates the microphone questions =), but I decided to get myself a propoer shotgun mic for capturing SFX and maybe dialogue (outside). I already searched the web and SSD but I still need to ask, because my question haven`t been answered yet.

Right know I have a Rode NT4, a SM57 a cheap contact mix and a Rode NT1 plus my Tascam HDP2. Now, as I said above, I want to buy a proper shotgun mic. My budget would be around 1,9K $ or 1,6K €.

So my plan is to rent some shotgun mics and see which one I like most and here comes the actual question.
So far I want to rent a MKH416, a Sanken CS3e (hard to get here) and a Neumann KMR 81. Do you have any other mics in mind that I should rent and compare to the oter three?

Thanks and I hope you people don`t hate me for asking this kind of question =)

Comment: Fter several days of testing, I ordered the Neumann KMR81. The schoeps CMIT 5 is awesome in rooms that do have a lot of reflections, but it had a higher noisefloor and was less directional compared to the MKH and the Neumann.
Nevertheless, if I should boom inside, I would go for the Schoeps (rent it). 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Short shotguns I would look for;

- Sennheiser MKH60
- Schoeps CMIT
- DPA 4017

all are around $2k as far as I know

I would also try the Rode NTG3, apparently they stand up quite well to more expensive microphones & could save you $1k+

Comment: Great advice, IMO. I've never used it myself, but I've been on shoots where the CMIT was used; it is the best sounding shotgun I've ever heard. Even indoors, within reason. The MKH-60 also gives great results at insanely low noise levels. I'm sure the DPA unit is nice, but I've never heard the results.

Comment: And the price range expands =). Well I guess I have to try the Schoeps after these words

Answer (score 1):

Hi Michael,

If you're seriously considering the Schoeps CMIT 5U then then you should check out this [good review on Matthew Share's blog](http://www.electronicmath.com/?p=542). He details his experiences of using the CMIT at a recent shoot in Canada. It's probably worth a read if you're looking into getting one...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you also want to consider a stereo shotgun? Sennheiser do a stereo version of the MKH416 the MKH418, it is an MS mic. I use it regularly, just make sure you have a good windjammer for it, I use the Rycote Windjammer (kit4).